# how to parse large xml file(3.8 mb) in 40 seconds from url using saxparser in android?

Tags: android, saxparser

Iam using sax parser to parse the xml file of 3.8 mb. Its loading time while parsing is almost about 3.5 minutes.

```
public class sentmsghandler extends DefaultHandler {
public folder folderobj;
public Contact contact;
public Parent parent;
public Student student;
private StringBuilder builder;
Boolean repeat;

public folder getfolder() {
    return folderobj;
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
    // Log.i("testing parent contact",localName);
    if (this.folderobj != null) {

        String st = builder.toString();
        if (localName.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
                BaseFeedParser.SchoolName.toUpperCase())) {
            folderobj.setSchoolName(st);
        } else if (localName.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
                BaseFeedParser.ParentCode.toUpperCase())) {
            parent.setParentCode(st);
        } else if (localName.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
                BaseFeedParser.FamilyCode.toUpperCase())) {
            if (!repeat) {
                parent.setFamilyCode(st);
            } else {
                student.setFamilyCode(st);
            }
        }

        else if (localName.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
                BaseFeedParser.FamilyName.toUpperCase())) {

            if (!repeat) {
                parent.setFamilyName(st);
            } else {
                student.setFamilyName(st);
            }
        }

        else if (localName.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
                BaseFeedParser.GivenNames.toUpperCase())) {

            if (!repeat) {
                parent.setGivenNames(st);
            } else {
                student.setGivenNames(st);
            }
        } else if (localName.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
                BaseFeedParser.ParentType.toUpperCase())) {
            parent.setParentType(st);
        } else if (localName.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
                BaseFeedParser.EmailAddress.toUpperCase())) {
            parent.setEmailAddress(st);
        } else if (localName.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
                BaseFeedParser.MobilePhone.toUpperCase())) {
            parent.setMobilePhone(st);
        } else if (localName.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
                BaseFeedParser.LandLineNumber.toUpperCase())) {
            parent.setLandLineNumber(st);
        } else if (localName.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
                BaseFeedParser.Primary.toUpperCase())) {
            parent.setPrimary(st);
        } else if (localName.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
                BaseFeedParser.StudentCode.toUpperCase())) {
            student.setStudentCode(st);
        } else if (localName.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
                BaseFeedParser.SchoolYearLevel.toUpperCase())) {
            student.setSchoolYearLevel(st);
        } else if (localName.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
                BaseFeedParser.RollClass.toUpperCase())) {
            student.setRollClass(st);
        } else if (localName.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
                BaseFeedParser.House.toUpperCase())) {
            student.setHouse(st);
        }

    }
    builder.setLength(0);
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);

    if (localName.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
            BaseFeedParser.Folder.toUpperCase())) {
        folderobj = new folder();
    }

    else if (localName.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
            BaseFeedParser.Contact.toUpperCase())) {
        contact = new Contact();
        folderobj.getContact_list().add(contact);
    } else if (localName.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
            BaseFeedParser.Parent.toUpperCase())) {
        parent = new Parent();
        repeat = false;
        contact.getParent_list().add(parent);
    } else if (localName.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
            BaseFeedParser.Student.toUpperCase())) {
        student = new Student();
        repeat = true;
        parent.getStudent_list().add(student);
    }

}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.characters(ch, start, length);
    builder.append(ch, start, length);
}

@Override
public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.startDocument();
    folderobj = new folder();
    builder = new StringBuilder();
    repeat = false;
}
```

}

Saxfeedparser.java

```
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

public class SaxFeedParser extends BaseFeedParser {

    public SaxFeedParser(String feedUrl) {
        super(feedUrl);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public folder parse() throws RuntimeException {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        sentmsghandler handler = null;
        try {
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            handler = new sentmsghandler();
            parser.parse(this.getInputStream(), handler);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        return handler.getfolder();
    }

}
```

Basefeedparser.java

```
public abstract class BaseFeedParser implements SentParser {

    // names of the XML tags
    static final String Folder = "Folder";
    static final String SchoolName = "SchoolName";
    static final String Contact = "Contact";
    static final String Parent = "Parent";
    static final String ParentCode = "ParentCode";
    static final String FamilyCode = "FamilyCode";
    static final String FamilyName = "FamilyName";
    static final String GivenNames = "GivenNames";
    static final String ParentType = "ParentType";
    static final String EmailAddress = "EmailAddress";
    static final String MobilePhone = "MobilePhone";
    static final String LandLineNumber = "LandLineNumber";
    static final String Primary = "Primary";
    static final String Student = "Student";
    static final String StudentCode = "StudentCode";
    static final String SchoolYearLevel = "SchoolYearLevel";
    static final String RollClass = "RollClass";
    static final String House = "House";

    //

    final URL feedUrl;

    protected BaseFeedParser(String feedUrl) {
        try {
            this.feedUrl = new URL(feedUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    protected InputStream getInputStream() {
        try {
            return feedUrl.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling the code in activity with

```
SaxFeedParser sax = new SaxFeedParser("link");// /check parents.xml
folder result = sax.parse();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could improve:

instead of doing

```
localName.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
            BaseFeedParser.Contact.toUpperCase()
```

all the time, save `BaseFeedParser.Contact` as uppercase already, and convert `localName` only once into uppercase

```
localName = localName.toUpperCase();
if (localName.equals(BaseFeedParser.Folder)) {
    // something
} else if (localName.equals(BaseFeedParser.Contact)) {
   // something else
} else if (localName.equals(BaseFeedParser.Parent)) {
  // something here
}
```

That should give you a bit of a speed boost.

If you know that the case does not change you can even leave out the uppercasing completely.

another technique that might speed up the string comparisons is to use a HashMap

```
private static final int CASE_FOLDER = 1;
private static final int CASE_SCHOOLNAME = 2;
private static final HashMap<String, Integer> MAP = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
static {
    MAP.put("FOLDER", CASE_FOLDER);
    MAP.put("SCHOOLNAME", CASE_SCHOOLNAME);
}
```

then do

```
localName = localName.toUpperCase();
int match = MAP.get(localName);
switch (match) {
    case CASE_FOLDER:
        // do something
        break;
 // etc
}
```